# Чтение строк из файла. Каждую новую строку в новую переменную

Tags: c++, файловый-ввод-вывод

```
string sitename[50];
string number[50];
string email[50];
string password[50];

ifstream in("file.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            in >> sitename[i];
            in >> number[i];
            in >> email[i];
            in >> password[i];
        }
```

У меня есть текстовый файл, где в первой строчке лежит соответственно имя сайта, во второй номер телефона и т.д. Как исправить код, чтобы первая строка файла заносилась в переменную sitename, вторая в number и после password снова в sitename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `std::getline` из `<string>`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline.

Пример кода, который тебе, вероятно, хочется написать:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    const int N = 50;
    std::string sitename[N];
    std::string number[N];
    std::string email[N];
    std::string password[N];

    std::ifstream in("file.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::getline(in, sitename[i]);
        std::getline(in, number[i]);
        std::getline(in, email[i]);
        std::getline(in, password[i]);
    }
}
```